# JSON.parse error if i save JSON with single quotes to a variable

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

Hi i am getting messages JSON array from my controller to my jsp header i am saving this JSON array to a variable in javascript with singlequotes like below

```js
var m1='[{"datestamp":"-2","id":"1","message":"<span class=\"cblue\">Suresh MB<\/span> wants to join company please click <span class=\"cgreen\"><a href=\"getAllRegistrationRequests\">here<\/a><\/span> to see other requests","ismessageread":"1"},{"datestamp":"-3","id":"2","message":"<span class=\"cblue\">Wilson<\/span> has been <span class=\"cgreen\">Unlocked<\/span>","ismessageread":"1"},{"datestamp":"-3","id":"3","message":"<span class=\"cblue\">Wilson<\/span> has been <span class=\"cgreen\">Unlocked<\/span>","ismessageread":"1"}]';  

m1=JSON.parse(m1);

console.log(m1);
```

why i am getting JSON.parse error for the below code
m1=JSON.parse(m1);

I have to save data within a single quotes because I may not a get for data messages that time code will be

var m1=;

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: It seems like you're saving the string that will execute, and not an actual reference to an object, so within the JSON string, if you have a double quote, it will break the JSON string. From what you're describing, that is what it seems to me.

Comment: here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wsumtayj/

Comment: @JoelHager yes you are right. how to avoid this, because in some cases I may not get data from my server.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace all `/"` to `/'` in value of properties as following:

```js
var m1='[{"datestamp":"-2","id":"1","message":"<span class=\'cblue\'>Suresh MB<\/span> wants to join company please click <span class=\'cgreen\'><a href=\'getAllRegistrationRequests\'>here<\/a><\/span> to see other requests","ismessageread":"1"},{"datestamp":"-3","id":"2","message":"<span class=\'cblue\'>Wilson<\/span> has been <span class=\'cgreen\'>Unlocked<\/span>","ismessageread":"1"},{"datestamp":"-3","id":"3","message":"<span class=\'cblue\'>Wilson<\/span> has been <span class=\'cgreen\'>Unlocked<\/span>","ismessageread":"1"}]';  

m1=JSON.parse(m1);

console.log(m1);
```